# How to replace value of column in a row in ListView using C#.net?

Tags: c#, windows, listview

```
ID      Item          Code
1       Item a        1565
2       Item x        **2565**
3       Item w        1245
4       Item f        1345
```

I have a ListView Details format like above and I want to change the value of a cell content which is in between ** mark.
How can I change it such a way that it will appear in same row and without need of updating other values in a row or a table.

Please Guide me in C#.net

Comment: How do you wish to identify the row that needs changing?

Comment: How do you fill the listview ? Changing the value is basically the same, but instead of adding a new item, you just modify a property of it...

Comment: Just assign the entire row.  ListView is smart enough to only do work when the value changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it depends on how you fill your `ListView`.

Anyway, a code like this, should work in almost every situations:

```
var idIdx = listView1.Columns["ID"].Index;
var codeIdx = listView1.Columns["Code"].Index;

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    if (item.SubItems[idIdx].Text == "2")
    {
        item.SubItems[codeIdx].Text = "new value...";
        break;
    }
}
```

**Just a caveat:**

to assure the first 2 lines of this code work, you must properly initialize your columns' `Name` property, when you create them:

either by using the proper add overload:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("ID", "ID");
```

or by setting it later:

```
var col = listView1.Columns.Add("ID");
col.Name = "ID";
```